How to Extend OSEK-Based OS to Support Multiple Schedule Tables for SyncScheduleTable API Implementation?
Question:
I am working on extending an OSEK-based OS to implement the SyncScheduleTable API as specified in AUTOSAR 4.4.0. Our current OS only supports a single schedule table, but synchronization requires managing multiple schedule tables. Below is the list of APIs supported in our existing OS for schedule table management:
Existing APIs:

Os_StatusType Os_Fn_StartScheduleTableRel(Os_ScheduleTBLType ScheduleTableID, Os_Base_Type Offset);

Os_StatusType Os_Fn_StartScheduleTableAbs(Os_ScheduleTBLType ScheduleTableID, Os_Base_Type Start);

Os_StatusType Os_Fn_StopScheduleTable(Os_ScheduleTBLType ScheduleTableID);

void Os_Fn_ScheduleTblMainFunction(void);

void Os_Fn_ScheduleTblInit(void);

void Os_Fn_ScheduleTblDeInit(void);


Newly Implemented APIs:

Os_StatusType Os_Fn_SyncScheduleTable(ScheduleTableType ScheduleTableID, uint32_t Sync_Counter);

Os_StatusType Os_Fn_GetScheduleTableStatus(ScheduleTableType ScheduleTableID, ScheduleTableStatusRefType ScheduleStatus);

Os_StatusType Os_Fn_NextScheduleTable(ScheduleTableType ScheduleTableID_From, ScheduleTableType ScheduleTableID_To);
Here is my implementation of the Os_Fn_SyncScheduleTable API:
Os_StatusType Os_Fn_SyncScheduleTable(ScheduleTableType ScheduleTableID, uint32_t Sync_Counter)
{
   /* Local Variables */
   Os_Schedule_Tbl_Type_St* fl_SchdTbL_St;
   uint32_t fl_deviation_size_u32 = 0u;
   uint32_t fl_duration_size_u32 = 0u;

   Os_StatusType status = E_OS_OK;

   /* Check if the Schedule Table ID is valid */
   if (ScheduleTableID >= MAX_SCHEDULE_TBL_ID)
   {
       return E_OS_ID; // Invalid Schedule Table ID
   }

   /* Get the schedule table object */
   fl_SchdTbL_St = &OS_Core_Dynamic_st[g_Os_Current_App_Mode_u32].Schedule_Tbl_St[ScheduleTableID];

   /* Ensure the schedule table is configured for synchronization */
   if (fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Tbl_SyncType == OS_SCHT_SYNC_IMPLICIT ||
       fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Tbl_SyncType == OS_SCHT_SYNC_NON)
   {
       return E_OS_ID; // Synchronization not supported or misconfigured
   }

   /* Ensure the schedule table is running */
   if (fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Tbl_State == SCHEDULETABLE_STOPPED || fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Tbl_State == SCHEDULETABLE_NEXT)
   {
       return E_OS_STATE; // Schedule table is not running
   }

   /* Retrieve the duration of the schedule table */
   fl_duration_size_u32 = fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Final_Delay;

   /* Calculate the fl_deviation_size_u32 */
   fl_deviation_size_u32 = (Sync_Counter - fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_SysTick_Counter_Stamp) % fl_duration_size_u32;

   /* Adjust fl_deviation_size_u32 to be positive */
   if (fl_deviation_size_u32 < 0) {
       fl_deviation_size_u32 += fl_duration_size_u32;
   }

   /* Check if fl_deviation_size_u32 exceeds allowed bounds */
   if (fl_deviation_size_u32 > OS_COUNTER_MAX_ALLOWED_VALUE)
   {
       status = E_OS_VALUE; // fl_deviation_size_u32 too large
   } else {
       /* Update the system tick stamp for synchronization */
       fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_SysTick_Counter_Stamp = Sync_Counter % fl_duration_size_u32;
       fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Current_Expiry_Point = fl_deviation_size_u32; // Adjust expiry point
       fl_SchdTbL_St->Schd_Expiry_Point_State = SERVE_EXP_POINT_OFFSET; // Sync state
   }

   return status;
}


This implementation assumes that the OS can manage multiple schedule tables, but our current OS supports only one. I am trying to determine how to extend our OS to manage multiple schedule tables effectively.
My Questions:

How can I modify or extend the current OS to support multiple schedule tables for synchronization?

Does my implementation of Os_Fn_SyncScheduleTable meet the AUTOSAR 4.4.0 specification requirements? If not, what improvements are needed?

How do the existing APIs like Os_Fn_StartScheduleTableRel and Os_Fn_NextScheduleTable interact with the newly implemented synchronization API?




